# Stuck on UEFI splash screen

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, uefi

My PC is stuck on the UEFI splash screen *(screen with UEFI logo and F-key options)* and the PC isn't responding to anything, including the keyboard, and the only way to exit is to physically shut it down.

- I have been using this same setup since 2015 and saw a lot of people having this problem when RAM was changed or plugged in the wrong slots, but I haven't moved the RAM since 2015
- I don't overclock, with RAM and CPU running at default voltages
- The only UEFI setting that is non-default is CSM [Compatibility Support Module] Mode is disabled in order to fix [Error 0xc1900101](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-update-2004-error-0xc1900101/61dbd698-f5bb-43b7-9a32-b9c4a178f281?page=2) for Windows 10 (CSM Mode is not used after Windows 8 anyway)
- Others had this issue after a UEFI firmware upgrade, but I have been using v5.80 for months without an issue before this happened, and I won't try to upgrade to UEFI v6.0+ since v5.80 is the last release compatible with Summit Ridge CPU; Asrock officially states:

  > ASRock does NOT recommend updating this BIOS if Pinnacle, Raven, Summit, or Bristol Ridge CPU is being used on your system.

---

**Specs:**

- **MB:** [AsRock AB350 Pro 4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/index.asp)
- **UEFI:** v5.80 (AGESA 1.0.0.1)
- **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 5 1600X (Summit Ridge)
- **RAM:** 2x 8GB DDR4 Ballistix Elite 
   *(unsure of the exact model, may be BLE8G4D26AFEA or BLE2C8G4D26AFEA)*

---

**What hasn't worked:**

- Rebooting the PC
- Powering down the PSU (switch and cord), pressing the power button for several seconds to discharge the MB circuit, then turning the PSU back on and booting

**What has worked:** Clearing CMOS

1. Switched off PSU and cleared CMOS by changing the jumper [[Manual page 25](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/AB350%20Pro4.pdf)]
2. Switched PC on (locked in a 3s boot loop), switched off PSU, and changed the jumper back to normal position
3. Switched PC on, PC reboots ~3x in a ~3s loop, then it worked normally again

I have been able to use my PC for ~2d, rebooting it several times without issue, then the issue began again, and it will be a nightmare if I have to open my case and reset the CMOS every 2 days.

Any clue of the origin of the issue?

Comment: Have you tried reflashing v5.80? An FYI to ensure correct info is disseminated: [CSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) [Legacy] Mode should never be enabled on any motherboard with an OS install after 2017, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017 _(Windows has supported EFI boot since Win 7)_, emulating BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment, and it will cause performance degradation _(boot times increase, GPT can't be used, etc.)_.